# Eclipse switches to Local History view from Git History

Tags: eclipse, egit

Unfortunately, I cannot guess preconditions for this behaviour. Because I faced with it on one (virtual) machine with Ubuntu while on the other one with Arch it is not reproduced. On both systems the Eclipse IDEs are installed *not* via OS package managers (i.e., downloaded and unpacked in home directory). All IDEs (BTW, the Eclipse CDT) are up to date.

Steps:

- switch to the Git perspective
- chose the History view
- check the "Link with Editor and Selection" button on its toolbar
- select some repository on the Git Repositories view; after that the selected repository's history is shown in the History view as described in the EGit documentation (i.e., with commits, corresponding buttons appears on the view's toolbar)
- open any file from this repository and click on it; after that, if the "Link with Editor and Selection" button on the History view's toolbar is still checked, the History view is switched to the Local History mode on one of my systems; this mode is described [here](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-06/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-55.htm?cp=0_1_0_17), to be clear

On the other of my systems, the History view remains being "git". Plus, the "Change
the File Scope for the History" tool-button becomes enabled and I can filter commits using this button.

As far as I understand, there is some trouble in choosing right Eclipse plugin to show the history, but I cannot imagine which and how to fix it.

Comment: To be clear, when you say Eclipse is "up to date", you're using the latest available version, which is 2020-06?  From what I can see, the only obvious way to make the history view change to local history is to select a file that does not reside in a git repository.  Are you 100% certain you are selecting a file from a git repo?

Comment: @DavidM.Karr, yes, I use the 2020-06 version.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to David M. Karr, I found that if a git repository is placed *not* at the same path-level as an Eclipse project containing it (below, for example, as in my case), then the behaviour mentioned in the question is observed. If I close the Eclipse project (it's not necessary even to delete it from Eclipse projects list) and open the same file using the Git Repositories view, I'm getting the desired bahaviour.